Why is there no "internal" part of linear momentum?
One of the ways to derive the expression for how angular momentum operators act on fields from the corresponding action on coordinates is to define spin as $$M_{\mu \nu} \Phi(0) = S_{\mu \nu} \Phi(0) \tag{1}$$ and then conjugate via translations $$ M_{\mu \nu} \Phi(x)= e^{-i x.P} M_{\mu \nu} e^{i x.P} \Phi(0)$$ which gives me both the orbital and the spin angular momentum parts. Similarly, one can find out the transformation of dilatations and special conformal transformations on fields. The case of translations should be trivially easy. I get the correct transformation law if I do the following $$P_{\mu} \Phi(x)=e^{x.P}(e^{-x.P} P_{\mu} e^{x.P}) \Phi(0)=e^{x.P} P_{\mu} \Phi(0)\color{red}= e^{x.P} (-i\partial_\mu)\Phi(0)= -i\partial_{\mu} e^{x.P}\Phi(0)=-i\partial_{\mu} \Phi(x)$$. The above works if I assume $$P_{\mu} \Phi(0)=-i \partial_\mu \Phi(0) \tag{2}$$ as in the step marked with equality marked in red.
I need a justification of the above equation. Why is this not $P_{\mu} \Phi(0)=k_\mu \Phi(0)$ like in $(1)$? Since $-i \partial_{\mu}$ is the momentum generator in terms of position coordinates i.e. "external part" I expected its appearance after translating via conjugations just like we get the orbital angular momentum i.e. "external" part only after translating via conjugations. But that's not what the above calculation is saying. This makes me wonder that in this logic why and when is an internal part like in $(1)$ even allowed?
So in a nutshell I am asking why is there a spin/internal part there for angular momentum while there is nothing as such for linear momentum?
N.B. I am asking for a theoretically motivated answer and not "because it works in real life" type experimental answers. I acknowledge that the theories are built to describe experimental phenomena and there's no "spin" part of linear momenta in nature, but I want to see in an intuitive/deep sense where this assumption goes into in the formalism or if it is a choice/definition.
EDIT In response to Valter Morretti's comment, $\Phi(x)$ is indeed a field operator which is supposed to transform as a conformal quasiprimary at the end of the calculation. The kind of calculation I am doing here is present in Francesco-Mathieu-Senechal's Yellow book on CFT.

I cannot understand what $\Phi(x)$ is. It is not a field operator as far as I understand. Please define it.

I believe this is related to https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/248065 and https://mathoverflow.net/q/235652 although I don't have a formal proof that internal linear momentum would be equivalent to an irreducible representation where translation acts nontrivially.
